# Carousel not working nor responding

Tags: html

I have made a carousel and it doesn't work automatically nor does it respond to a manual control. 
The arrows on the side won't respond.

I made the carousel from W3Schools and I was certain that it will work, but it doesnt.

You can find my code on [Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vrRbpX)
My code:

```
    <head>
        <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    </head>

    <body>

        <div class="container">
      <h2>Carousel Example</h2>  


            <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
            <!-- Indicators -->
            <ol class="carousel-indicators">
              <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
              <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
              <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
            </ol>

            <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
            <div class="carousel-inner">
              <div class="item active">
                <img src="https://www.derekprincearmenia.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/56699-nature-beauty-600x400.jpg" alt="Los Angeles" style="width:100%;">
              </div>

              <div class="item">
                <img src="http://globalmedicalco.com/photos/globalmedicalco/18/85311.png" alt="Chicago" style="width:100%;">
              </div>   

              <div class="item">
                <img src="http://stipsy.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/Hamilton-Pool-Nature-Preserve-9-600x400.jpg" alt="New york" style="width:100%;">
              </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Left and right controls -->
            <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
              <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
            </a>
            <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
              <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>

    </body>
```

Comment: Would be great to see the code for this.

Comment: There is still missing the head, scripts, anything like that?

Comment: I have this in the head:<title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

Comment: I recommend avoiding w3schools at all costs, use MDN or Boostrap's documentation.. w3schools has bad practices that should be avoided ..

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs, I was recommended that side, like it was supposed to be helpful for new people at coding

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs has a point though, as I've heard they've got some bad rep :/

Comment: @Nobody why would they do that? :/ read here w3fools http://www.w3fools.com/

Comment: @Nobody and I think you are missing main scripts, (learned that the hard way, myself ^^)

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs wow, didn't even know. Thanks for the info :)

Comment: @Nobody no worries :) much better to start using best practices rather than getting a year in and having to redo everything *trauma from past sets in*

Comment: haha you are right

Comment: Thank you all for help. it now works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this inbetween your `<head></head>`:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

These are main scripts you would need, the one for bootstrap and jquery

Comment: I can't see anything

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me. Hope it helps. What you needed to add into you `<head>` tags was the following scripts:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Carousel Example</h2>  
  <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>

    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="item active">
        <img src="https://www.derekprincearmenia.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/56699-nature-beauty-600x400.jpg" alt="Los Angeles" style="width:100%;">
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <img src="http://globalmedicalco.com/photos/globalmedicalco/18/85311.png" alt="Chicago" style="width:100%;">
      </div>
    
      <div class="item">
        <img src="http://stipsy.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/Hamilton-Pool-Nature-Preserve-9-600x400.jpg" alt="New york" style="width:100%;">
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Left and right controls -->
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you should add an explanation so OP understands the issue